# CSS positioning discrepancy between chrome/safari and firefox

Tags: css, positioning

OK, so I have tried a number of things to fix this issue, but I must be missing something.  I am new to this and learning as I go using firebug which is making this particular problem hard to solve for me.  My site (under development) works fine in firefox, but there is a vertical gap between the search bar and categories bar in chrome and safari.  See here:

http://how2garage.com/

You can see the gap between the red search bar and black category bar in Chrome.  At first I thought it was the "blog description," but I set that to display none and it didn't help.  I also tried switching the position definition and couldn't fix this issue in Chrome without messing it up in Firefox.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
#header { 
  padding:0 0 20px 0;
}
```

in your css.. ( Style.css, line 54 )

You  should remove the padding.

Comment: Wow, that simple huh?  Thanks, that fixed it.  Would you mind explaining why Safari and Chrome used this padding, but firefox didn't?  I didn't even consider checking the parent theme css because I figured all three browsers would have issues if it was something in the parent.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tim said, "#header" style has a 20px padding and at the bottom of your css file you have :

```
#header, x:-moz-any-link, x:default {
    padding: 0;
}
```

And this is why in Firefox you do not see the gap.